# How many ways can 5 students be seated in a row of 6 chairs if 2 students must sit togegher?

Tags: permutations

The 2 adjacent students will have an arrangement of 5.  Next, the open 4 chairs can be filled by either of the 3 students for 3!= 6.  The product of 5 and 6 = 30.  Am I taking the proper approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it is how many ways can 5 things (the pair, the other 3 students, and the empty seat) be arranged.  And then for each of those arrangements, there are multiple ways the pair can be arranged, so multiply by that number.

Answer (score 0):

You are not ordering the couple and you are not taking into account that there are $4$ available seats after seating the two people that must be together. The first part is good.

There are $5$ ways to select the two adjacent seats for the two adjacent students and then $2$ ways to select which one sits in which of the two seats. After this there are $4$ empty seats for $3$ people. There are $4$ ways to pick the empty seat, and after this there are indeed $3!$ ways to distribute the $3$ students in the $3$ selected seats.

hence the final answer is $5\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 3!=40\cdot 6=240$